# Проблема с bind_param в mysqli

Tags: mysqli, php

Говорит это, мучаюсь часа 2
*Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in Z:\home\test1.ru\www\core\modules\admin\admin.php

```
$sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE pages title = ?,url = ?,text = ?, description = ?,index = 0 keywords = ? WHERE id = ?");
            $sql->bind_param('sssssi',$title,$url,$text,$description,$keywords,$id);
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $url = $_POST['url'];
            $text = $_POST['text'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];

            $sql->execute() or die("Предупреждение о неудачном запросе");  //Выполняем запрос
```

Comment: `UPDATE pages SET title = ?,url = ?,text = ?, description = ?,index = 0 keywords = ? WHERE id = ?`

А вообще не красиво выглядит всё, брр. Используйте PDO.

Comment: Вполне красиво, а про PDO слышать не хочу

Comment: @Алексей Скляр чем так PDO не угодил? И у вас заработало?

Comment: просто не нравится pdo, я прошу с этой проблемой помочь, а не выяснять неприязнь к расширениям

Comment: @Алексей Скляр я вам написал ответ, вы пропустили SET.